# Вывод данных из json массива по условию

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, база-данных, json

Помогите разобраться, я никак не могу понять, как вывести нужны данные из json массива.

Итак, есть запрос к БД, который перебирает все строки в БД и затем шифрует его в json:

```
$getAllStaffCh = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM staffgrafic WHERE namehash='$user'");
$rowsAllStaffCh = mysqli_num_rows($getAllStaffCh);
$dataCh = array();

if($rowsAllStaffCh > 0) {
    while($rowAllStaffCh = $getAllStaffCh->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataCh[] = $rowAllStaffCh;
    }
    $encodedRows = json_encode($dataCh);
}
```

Как в другом месте, вывести данные из этого json по нужным условиям?

Например, есть столбец на сайте с нужным годом записи определенного пользователя, вот как из данного json массива вывести данные, которые будут соответствовать условию, скажем, году `2019-11-11` и пользователю `user11` ?

(Таких условий может быть более 100 на одной странице, поэтому каждый раз делать запросы mysql я не хочу)

Answer (score 0):

> Таких условий может быть более 100 на одной странице

Все таки лучше добавить условия в sql запрос и выбирать не все поля таблицы, так Вы избежите переполнение памяти

Похожий вопрос на Ваш задавался ранее 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987611/how-to-search-through-a-json-array-in-php